# firefox block image from other site... not chrome

Tags: css, image, firefox, cross-domain

Im using firefox and I find this tutorial, but there is a problem, nothing appear on FF instead of Google Chrome :

https://codepen.io/akella/pen/XWYrRmb

```
url("http://allyourhtml.club/carousel/pattern.webp")
```

it's a cross domain issue, but how can I allow image by default?

Comment: Have you tried changing the url to `https` instead of `http`? What is the exact error message appearing in your Firefox console? It's up to the web **server** (allyourhtml.club, in this case) to determine whether or not images it serves can be used in cross-domain contexts ... if the server prohibits it, there's nothing you can do about it. Except that you can always serve your own images.

Comment: `Content-Security-Policy : La requête non sécurisée « http://allyourhtml.club/carousel/image.webp » a été bloquée.` it's not my code, i lost time to understand why it works on chrome and not firefox... with https its works, but that seems if we have codepen, we must always rewrite all url... its borring, no better solution?

Comment: You could change your browser settings to [allow mixed content](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mixed-content-blocking-firefox).

Comment: but this not working for all user (if I have same thing on my site). Why Chrome dont apply his own Content-Security-Policy ?